# Should Read[] not close its Stream?

Tags: functions

I read a record from a file.

```
Read[file,Record];
```

It reads and opens a stream.

Should `Read` not close its stream after reading, like `ReadList` does?

```
ReadList[file,Record,1];
```

Comment: `ReadList` reads the whole content of a file, so it makes sense to close it afterwards, while `Read` only reads the next entry in the file (be it a number, line, record, whatever). This is by design.

Comment: Also note that `ReadList` only closes the stream afterwards if it was closed to begin with. I think you should regard the `ReadList` auto-closing behaviour as a convenient shortcut rather than "the way it should be".

Answer (score 5):

No, it should not.  Often the point of having streams (for files) in the first place is so that the file is not constantly re-opened and closed.

Comment: No doubts.   .   .Where I point to here is using Read to read one element of a file not a stream.   .   .Even the fact that Read is not intendet to read from a file, it does it.   .  .And it does it correct. And while doing so it opens a stream.   .  .My impression is it should at least give a hint you are doing something wrong.  .   .Or close that opened stream after reading.

Comment: @HpR You will note that I did not vote to close this answer as I felt it was valid question.  The community might have a kinder response to your questions if you showed interest in properly participating; as it stands you have voted only a few times and Accepted only two answers.  Why do you ignore my (and other) requests for you to participate in these ways?